# If Costigan Jr believes that being a cop is not his identity, then what exact identity is he looking for?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed (2006)*, after killing Mafia Boss Frank and receiving all the praise from his
colleagues, Sullivan meets Costigan Jr in his office:

> Sullivan: I understand. You wanna be a cop again.
>
> Costigan Jr: No, no. **Being a cop's not an identity. I want my identity
> back**. Check your computer. Go on. You'll have to excuse my behavior.

If Costigan Jr believes that being a cop is not his identity, then what exact identity is he looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Being a cop's not an identity. I want my identity back.

Sullivan offers him a *job* (being a cop) while Costigan wants a **life**: his name and history back just as before.